# How do I select a column from a list of dataframes and apply a function to eliminate values from a given row for that column?

Tags: r

I am relatively new to R programming and would like some help in processing some data I have.  I have a list of csv files which I've managed to successfully import as a list of dataframes in R.  Each of these dataframes have the same column headers but vary in the number of rows.

What I want to be able to do is to select the 3rd column from each of these dataframes and in each row for that column, loop through to remove all the values that are equal to zero.  Then afterwards in each dataframe, I want to simply count the number of rows that are left in each dataframe (nrows should work).  Would appreciate any help (and apologies if the solution has already been posted).

This is the code I have so far for importing the data:

```
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")
for(file in files)
{
perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
assign(
gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
read.csv(paste(path,file,sep="")))
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have created the `list` of `data.frame`

```
sapply(lst, function(x) nrow(x[x[,3]!=0,]))
```

#### data

```
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
lst <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```